# My discord.py bot hosting on heroku not getting online

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

Hey I have heard about heroku and wanna host on that so I make ab app on heroku setup everything but my not is is not getting online I am not getting any build error
You can check my github
https://github.com/reyyan987/organic
discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime

from urllib import parse, request
import re

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', description="This is a Helper Bot")

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

@bot.command()
async def sum(ctx, numOne: int, numTwo: int):
    await ctx.send(numOne + numTwo)

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.guild.name}", description="Lorem Ipsum asdasd", timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.add_field(name="Server created at", value=f"{ctx.guild.created_at}")
    embed.add_field(name="Server Owner", value=f"{ctx.guild.owner}")
    embed.add_field(name="Server Region", value=f"{ctx.guild.region}")
    embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=f"{ctx.guild.id}")
    # embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{ctx.guild.icon}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/python-7be70baaac.png")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def youtube(ctx, *, search):
    query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
    html_content = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    # print(html_content.read().decode())
    search_results = re.findall('href=\"\\/watch\\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
    print(search_results)
    # I will put just the first result, you can loop the response to show more results
    await ctx.send('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])

# Events
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="Tutorials", url="http://www.twitch.tv/accountname"))
    print('My Ready is Body')


@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    if "tutorial" in message.content.lower():
        # in this case don't respond with the word "Tutorial" or you will call the on_message event recursively
        await message.channel.send('This is that you want http://youtube.com/fazttech')
        await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run(os.getenv('Token'))
```

My requirements.text

```
 
discord.py
requests
```

I have tried
asyncio in place of request but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried running `heroku logs --tail` in the Command Prompt? If there is any error, it will show.

Comment: When you use `os.getenv()`, make sure that the token is stored as a Heroku Configuration variable. In order to do so: Navigate to the app => Click 'Settings' => Click 'Reveal Config Vars'). You can create a configuration variable there.

Comment: Let me check...

Comment: Yes it is stored

Comment: And its env not nev

Comment: I have also regenerated the token some times and changed the token in  cars

Comment: Sorry its config vars

Comment: Did you run `heroku logs --tail`? If there is an error in the code, it will crash the Dyno.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229211/discussion-between-jacob-lee-and-reyyan).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting those in your requirements text:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py 
dnspython==1.16.0 
PyNaCl==1.3.0 
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

Also make sure your .txt file is named `requirements` without `.txt` in the end

Comment: Ok sorry for late response I will try this

Comment: It didn't work it return error at only requirements Giles without text and with .txt and the code for thebgile you gave it say downloading Lind of thing for discord.py but not isn't online

Comment: Oh also try adding `discord.py==1.5.1` in those. If the error keeps going im not sure what causes that

Comment: OK let em do that

Comment: See the answer I submitted that are the errors

Comment: Im not sure... Look if there is any unecessary spaces i guess in your code when you import discord

Comment: OK let em check

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this in the logs

```
2021-02-26T08:21:20.856803+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python filename.py`
2021-02-26T08:21:21.541356+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-26T08:21:24.270010+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-26T08:21:24.340039+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-02-26T08:21:24.201416+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "filename.py", line 2
2021-02-26T08:21:24.201450+00:00 app[worker.1]:     import discord
2021-02-26T08:21:24.201450+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2021-02-26T08:21:24.201451+00:00 app[worker.1]: IndentationError: unexpected indent
```